# Clojure loop collection

Tags: clojure

I want to know if this is the right way to loop through an collection:

```
(def citrus-list ["lemon" "orange" "grapefruit"])

(defn display-citrus [citruses]
  (loop [[citrus & citruses] citruses]
    (println citrus)
    (if citrus (recur citruses))
    ))

(display-citrus citrus-list)
```

I have three questions:

1. the final print displays nil, is it ok or how can avoid it?
2. I understand what & is doing in this example but I don´t see it in other cases, maybe you could provide a few examples
3. Any other example to get the same result?

Thanks,
R.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with each item in the collection. If you just want to print as you are doing here then `doseq` is a good choice. However `map`, `reduce`, `loop/recur` and `iterate` can all go through all the items in a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your implementation is wrong. It would fail if your list contains `nil`:

```
user> (display-citrus [nil "asd" "fgh"])
;;=> nil
nil
```

And print unneeded nil if the list is empty:

```
user> (display-citrus [])
;;=> nil
nil
```

you can fix it this way:

```
(defn display-citrus [citruses]
  (when (seq citruses)
    (loop [[citrus & citruses] citruses]
      (println citrus)
      (if (seq citruses) (recur citruses)))))
```

1) it is totally ok: for non-empty collection the last call inside function is `println`, which returns `nil`, and for empty collection you don't call anything, meaning `nil` would be returned (clojure function **always** returns a value). To avoid nil in your case you should explicitly return some value (like this for example):

```
(defn display-citrus [citruses]
  (when (seq citruses)
    (loop [[citrus & citruses] citruses]
      (println citrus)
      (if (seq citruses) (recur citruses))))
  citruses)

user> (display-citrus citrus-list)
;;=> lemon
;;=> orange
;;=> grapefruit
["lemon" "orange" "grapefruit"]
```

2) some articles about [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) should help you

3) yes, there are some ways to do this. The simplest would be:

`(run! println citrus-list)`

Comment: Obviously. I just wanted to keep it as close to the op's variant as possible, so he could easily see the difference

Answer (score 2):

Answering your last question, you should avoid using `loop` in Clojure. This form is rather for experienced users that really know what they do. In your case, you may use such more user-friendly forms as `doseq`. For example:

```
(doseq [item collection]
  (println item))
```

You may also use `map` but keep in mind that it returns a new list (of `nil`s if your case) that not sometimes desirable. Say, you are interested only in printing but not in the result.

In addition, `map` is lazy and won't be evaluated until it has been printed or evaluated with `doall`.

Answer (score 1):

For most purpose, you can use either `map`, `for` or `loop`.

```
=> (map count citrus-list)
(5 6 10)

=> (for [c citrus-list] (count c))
(5 6 10)

=> (loop [[c & citrus] citrus-list
           counts []]
     (if-not c counts
       (recur citrus (conj counts (count c)))))
[5 6 10]
```

I tend to use `map` as much of possible. The syntax is more concise, and it clearly separates the control flow (sequential loop) from the transformation logic (count the values).

For instance, you can run the same operation (count) in parallel by simply replacing `map` by `pmap`

```
=> (pmap count citrus-list)
[5 6 10]
```

In Clojure, [most operations on collection are lazy](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/laziness.html). They will not take effect as long as your program doesn't need the new values. To apply the effect immediately, you can enclose your loop operation inside `doall`

```
=> (doall (map count citrus-list))
(5 6 10)
```

You can also use `doseq` if you don't care about return values. For instance, you can use `doseq` with `println` since the function will always return `nil`

```
=> (doseq [c citrus-list] (println c))
lemon
orange
grapefruit
```